# What do you call a person who doesn't get offended?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe a person who never really gets offended. Can it be described in one word?

Comment: I'd call them a "challenge".  (Though JOSH's "unflappable" would work, too.)

Comment: "Tolerant": *willing to accept feelings, habits, or beliefs that are different from your own; able to allow or accept something that is harmful, unpleasant, etc*.

Comment: True, but the question was meant to refer to a person who doesn't take  offense at personal insults and so on. You know like the disciples who went out praising God when they came from trial? or like how James wrote in James 1:2 -"My brethren, count it all joy when ye fall into divers temptations;".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[***Thick-skinned***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thick-skinned) is a possibility:

> **thick-skinned** - adjective
> ​
> Someone who is thick-skinned does not appear to be easily hurt by criticism:
>
> - You do need to be thick-skinned to survive as a politician here.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 11):

**[imperturbable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imperturbable)**:  incapable of being upset or agitated; not easily excited; calm: imperturbable composure.

Answer (score 10):

***​[Unflappable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unflappable)*** is an adjective you may use:

> - not likely to get worried, nervous, or angry even in difficult situations:
>
>   - *She's totally unflappable - you have to be when working in such a high-pressure environment.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 4):

***easy-going***

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/easygoing)

> not easily worried or angered; relaxed and rather casual; calm

(As an aside, such a person can be infuriating.)

Answer (score 2):

[***Phlegmatic***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/phlegmatic) is one of the "four temperaments" with the others being Melancholic, Sanguine, and Choleric [From the concept of Four Humors of Greco-Roman medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_temperaments)

> **Phlegmatic** - adjective

1. not easily excited to action or display of emotion; apathetic; sluggish.
2. self-possessed, calm, or composed.

Answer (score 2):

I call him Mr **Teflon**, since criticism can't stick to him. I recall this word was employed for U.S. presidents whose popularity couldn't be affected by any scandal. I saw this word used in many occasions to describe someone who acts as if nothing affects him.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: No, but just googling 'teflon president' leads to a lot of articles refering to president reagan and later the term seems to have passed to common  usage.

Comment: I was just asking because I saw "I call him" and interpreted that as personal opinion, but I see what you're saying. +1

Answer (score 1):

You say it never **really** gets offended. One that never gets offended could be *imperturbable* or *thick-skinned*, but in both cases, the word makes me think that they don't react at all.

Someone that *does* react, but is not offended (for example s/he may reply politely to deny an accusation of being born out of wedlock), I'd call a **tolerant** person.

Answer (score 1):

How about **equanimous**?

Dictionary.com:

> [**equanimous**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equanimous): having or
>   showing equanimity; even-tempered
>
> [**equanimity**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equanimity): mental or
>   emotional stability or composure, especially under tension or strain;
>   calmness; equilibrium

Comment: Your choice of word is testament to your sanguine outlook on life. I can't be fairer than that, Rich. The Season's Greetings!

Comment: @PeterPoint You, too! All the best.